# Convert array structure from first array to second

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

This is my multi dimensional array.
Output should be in array2 structure.
I have tried many ways covert above array in easy but all came up with bulky code and lots of iteration.
Is there any easy way to do so?

I am a new in angular and JavaScript.

```
var array1=[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Johny",
        "category": [
            {
                "id": 12,
                "name": "GUI",
                "status": {
                    "id": 123,
                    "status": "working",
                    "name": "GUI"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 13,
                "name": "GFX",
                "status": {
                    "id": 124,
                    "status": "working",
                    "name": "GFX"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 14,
                "name": "UI",
                "status": {
                    "id": 125,
                    "status": "working",
                    "name": "UI"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Paul",
        "category": [
            {
                "id": 21,
                "name": "GUI",
                "status": {
                    "id": 212,
                    "status": "Progress",
                    "name": "GUI"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 22,
                "name": "GFX",
                "status": {
                    "id": 221,
                    "status": "working",
                    "name": "GFX"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 23,
                "name": "DM",
                "status": {
                    "id": 231,
                    "status": "done",
                    "name": "DM"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to change into this array2.

```
var array2=[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Johny",
        "category": [
            {
                "id": 12,
                "name": "GUI",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": 12,
                        "name": "GUI",
                        "status": {
                            "id": 123,
                            "status": "working",
                            "name": "GUI"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 21,
                        "name": "GUI",
                        "status": {
                            "id": 212,
                            "status": "Progress",
                            "name": "GUI"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 13,
                "name": "GFX",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": 13,
                        "name": "GFX",
                        "status": {
                            "id": 124,
                            "status": "working",
                            "name": "GFX"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 22,
                        "name": "GFX",
                        "status": {
                            "id": 221,
                            "status": "working",
                            "name": "GFX"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 14,
                "name": "UI",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": 14,
                        "name": "UI",
                        "status": {
                            "id": 125,
                            "status": "working",
                            "name": "UI"
                        }
                    },
                    //null data if not in first
                    {}
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 23,
                "name": "DM",
                "data": [
                    //null data if not in first
                    {},
                    {
                        "id": 23,
                        "name": "DM",
                        "status": {
                            "id": 231,
                            "status": "done",
                            "name": "DM"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Paul",
        "category": [
            {
                "id": 21,
                "name": "GUI",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": 12,
                        "name": "GUI",
                        "status": {
                            "id": 123,
                            "status": "working",
                            "name": "GUI"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 21,
                        "name": "GUI",
                        "status": {
                            "id": 212,
                            "status": "Progress",
                            "name": "GUI"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 22,
                "name": "GFX",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": 13,
                        "name": "GFX",
                        "status": {
                            "id": 124,
                            "status": "working",
                            "name": "GFX"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 22,
                        "name": "GFX",
                        "status": {
                            "id": 221,
                            "status": "working",
                            "name": "GFX"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 14,
                "name": "UI",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": 14,
                        "name": "UI",
                        "status": {
                            "id": 125,
                            "status": "working",
                            "name": "UI"
                        }
                    },
                    //null data if not in first
                    {}
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 23,
                "name": "DM",
                "data": [
                    //null data if not in first
                    {},
                    {
                        "id": 23,
                        "name": "DM",
                        "status": {
                            "id": 231,
                            "status": "done",
                            "name": "DM"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Output should be in array2 structure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you just want to have the original data as additional `data` attribute? This is simple using a `forEach()` loop in combination with the [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```
array1.forEach((obj) => {
    obj.category = obj.category.map((cat) => {
    return {id: cat.id, name: cat.name, data: cat}
  });
})
```

Hope this is what you're looking for :-)

Comment: I need additional modification in this on attribute data i want to push category object if key(name) value present in that category array else push null.